# have php got validate class or functions?

Tags: php, validation

I'm searching php validate functions. In my opinion regex is hard.

Has Php got ready function?

i want to validate this variable:

Telephone Numer
E-mail adress

Maybe More...

And i want to deactive html tags incoming data from textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Validate filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php), [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php).

For the HTML tags you can either [remove them](http://php.net/strip_tags) or [escape them](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions are going to be the most robust way to validate things like phone numbers and email addresses.

They're not too hard to learn if you have a good resource. And it's an excellent tool to have in your developer toolbox. Check out http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html. Otherwise, I'm sure you can find some existing validation functions by doing a search on Google or SO.

Take a look at [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/strip_tags) for removing HTML tags from strings.

Comment: but i dont want to remove html tags. i want similar to facebook wall post.

Comment: Fair enough. As noted by **Darhazer**, you can escape them.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`filter_var`](http://en.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

Answer (score 0):

Validating telephone numbers and email addresses is very hard, and complicated but conflicting opinions as to what constitutes a valid phone number (UK only? Some other country only? Multiple countries? What about extensions? Should the number be prefixed with a `+`? Are hyphens or other separating characters allowed?) or email address ([see one take on this](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)).

PHP has no built ins for this.